# Test if VBScript named argument exists

Tags: vbscript, command-line-arguments

I want to test if a specific named argument has been provided before validating that argument, so I can provide meaningful error codes for missing and invalid conditions.
I have this now

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colArgs = WScript.Arguments.Named

If colArgs.Item("Script") Then
    If not objFSO.FileExists(colArgs.Item("Script")) Then
        intReturn = 1805
    End If
Else
    intReturn = 1639
End If

If Not intReturn Then
    msgBox colArgs.Item("Script"), 0, "Script"
Else
    msgBox intReturn, 0, "Error"
End If
```

And my expectation would be that if I don't provide an argument called Script at all, I would get the Error msgBox with the 1639 value. Instead I get the good msgBox, with a blank for Script.
I also tried

```
If Not colArgs.Item("Script") = "" Then
```

EDIT: Per @Tomalak, I now have this

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell, objFSO, colArgs, intReturn

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colArgs = WScript.Arguments.Named

If Not IsEmpty(colArgs.Item("Script")) Then
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(colArgs.Item("Script")) Then
        intReturn = 1805
    End If
Else
    intReturn = 1639
End If

If IsEmpty(intReturn) Then
    msgBox colArgs.Item("Script"), 0, "Script"
Else
    msgBox intReturn, 0, "Error"
End If
```

And for what it is worth, I am calling the VBScript from PowerShell like this

```
$script = "\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools\Dev 4.0\#Spikes\Helper\Helper Target.ps1"
$arguments ="`"\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools\Dev 4.0\#Spikes\Helper\PxHelper.vbs`" //nologo /script:`"$script`" /wait:1"
Start-Process -filePath:Wscript.exe  -argumentList:$arguments
```

And now I get the error condition even when the script IS provided. Grrr, Mondays.

Comment: @tomalak I figured that was obvious enough to be assumed, but revised in any case.

Comment: It's better to always define everything you use in your sample code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a named argument is not given on the command line

- `WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("argname")` will return `False`
- `WScript.Arguments.Named("argname")` will return an *empty value*

If a named argument is given but not assigned a value on the command line (`/argname`)

- `WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("argname")` will return `True`
- `WScript.Arguments.Named("argname")` will return an *empty value*

If a named argument is given with an empty string on the command line (`/argname:`)

- `WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("argname")` will return `True`
- `WScript.Arguments.Named("argname")` will return an *empty string*

If a named argument is given with a value on the command line (`/argname:value`)

- `WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("argname")` will return `True`
- `WScript.Arguments.Named("argname")` will return a string with that value

Empty values are different from empty strings: They are uninitialized, whereas the empty string is a is regular string of zero length.

You can check for empty values with the `IsEmpty()` function.

```vb
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("foo") Then
    ' show message / end script / use default
End If

If IsEmpty(WScript.Arguments.Named("foo")) Then
    ' show message / end script / use default
End If
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried that, and it's still not working. But if I move `msgBox intReturn, 0, "Error"` outside of the conditional it correctly shows 1639. So it seems my issues is ALSO with `If Not intReturn Then`.

Comment: @Gordon You have replaced your `If colArgs.Item("Script") Then` line with this, right?

Comment: But... `If IsEmpty(intReturn) Then` does work. So same solution in both problem areas.

Comment: Arg, not so quick Gordon. It now shows the error all the time. I'll revise the OP.

Comment: @Gordon BTW You should **always** have `Option Explicit` on all your scripts. Using the default "on the fly" variable declaration is an invitation for nasty bugs.

Comment: Yeah, I am so used to PowerShell I had forgotten that. Added it with extended DIM and updated the OP. Still getting the error assigned to intReturn even when the script is provided.

Comment: @Gordon See updated answer, I completely forgot about `.Exists()`.

Comment: I've always used `WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("argname")` to return the string, but it looks like `WScript.Arguments.Named("argname")` is short-hand for this. Turns out `Item` is WshArguments' default property, as explained at https://www.itprotoday.com/devops-and-software-development/vbscripting-solutions-take-advantage-named-arguments

Comment: @Jimadine Yes, exactly. It's a common feature on COM objects - they can define a default method that is implicitly called when the user did not specify a method, but called "the object itself". This leads to a shorthand syntax. For Dictionary and Collection objects, `.Item()` is the default method.